# Excel Chart, X Axis timeline spacing

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a timeline I want to do on my chart, I have 2 issues,

1) The actual time , ie 1m, 3m, 6m, are not showing up on my x-axis, rather it is 0, 2, 4. How can I put the actual time here?

2) How do I make this timeline accurate in terms of spacing? 1-3 month should be small gap, but then something like 30-60Y should be longer.

Timeline:

[image]

Current chart:

[image]

As you can see the spacing is equal. I would like to space it somewhat in a more accurate fashion.
data:

```
+------+--------+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------+--------+--------+
| 0:00 |  10.00 | 75.00 | -75.00 | 20.00 | -55.00 | 75.00 |  -5.00 | -70.00 |  70.00 |  0.00 |   0.00 |   0.00 |
| 1m   |  20.00 | 75.00 | -75.00 | 22.50 | -52.50 | 70.00 | -10.00 | -60.00 |  60.00 | 10.00 | -10.00 |   0.00 |
| 3m   |  30.00 | 75.00 | -75.00 | 25.00 | -50.00 | 65.00 | -15.00 | -50.00 |  50.00 | 20.00 | -20.00 |   0.00 |
| 6m   |  40.00 | 75.00 | -75.00 | 27.50 | -47.50 | 60.00 | -20.00 | -40.00 |  40.00 | 30.00 | -30.00 |   0.00 |
| 1y   |  50.00 | 75.00 | -75.00 | 30.00 | -45.00 | 55.00 | -25.00 | -30.00 |  30.00 | 40.00 | -40.00 | -10.00 |
| 2y   |  60.00 | 75.00 | -75.00 | 32.50 | -42.50 | 50.00 | -30.00 | -20.00 |  20.00 | 50.00 | -50.00 | -10.00 |
| 3y   |  70.00 | 75.00 | -75.00 | 35.00 | -40.00 | 45.00 | -35.00 | -10.00 |  10.00 | 60.00 | -60.00 | -10.00 |
| 4y   |  80.00 | 75.00 | -75.00 | 37.50 | -37.50 | 40.00 | -40.00 |   0.00 |   0.00 | 65.00 | -65.00 | -10.00 |
| 5y   |  90.00 | 75.00 | -75.00 | 40.00 | -35.00 | 35.00 | -45.00 |  10.00 | -10.00 | 60.00 | -60.00 | -35.00 |
| 7y   | 100.00 | 75.00 | -75.00 | 42.50 | -32.50 | 30.00 | -50.00 |  20.00 | -20.00 | 50.00 | -50.00 | -35.00 |
| 10y  | 110.00 | 75.00 | -75.00 | 45.00 | -30.00 | 25.00 | -55.00 |  30.00 | -30.00 | 40.00 | -40.00 | -75.00 |
| 15y  | 120.00 | 75.00 | -75.00 | 47.50 | -27.50 | 20.00 | -60.00 |  40.00 | -40.00 | 30.00 | -30.00 | -75.00 |
| 20y  | 130.00 | 75.00 | -75.00 | 50.00 | -25.00 | 15.00 | -65.00 |  50.00 | -50.00 | 20.00 | -20.00 | -75.00 |
| 30y  | 140.00 | 75.00 | -75.00 | 52.50 | -22.50 | 10.00 | -70.00 |  60.00 | -60.00 | 10.00 | -10.00 | -75.00 |
| 60y  | 150.00 | 75.00 | -75.00 | 55.00 | -20.00 |  5.00 | -75.00 |  70.00 | -70.00 |  0.00 |   0.00 | -75.00 |
+------+--------+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------+--------+--------+
```

Axis options:

[image]

Any Help is appreciated!

Comment: Are those cells formatted as time or as text?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad formatted as number . Even if I format as 'time' they still remain.

Comment: They're probably not formatted as numbers since there is text in them... What happens when you select `Date Axis` under Axis options?

Comment: See updated picture. I changed it to axis format to time, see new picture uploaded. Date option kind of just makes it random dates. I just want to see like 1m , 2m, etc.

Comment: You may want to read [this](https://www.exceltactics.com/definitive-guide-using-dates-times-excel/)

Comment: What type of chart is it?  It looks like its treating the axis as categories.  Try an XY (scatter) chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that your time column is probably text.  Assuming your second time entry "1m" is in cell A2, use the following formula:

```
=ISNUMBER(A2)
```

A result of false means it is text

Second issue is the type of plot.  You will need to be using a scatter plot.  When using a scatter plot, the X axis will space out data proportionally to its value.  That is provided the data is all numerical.  When the data is not numerical, the scatter plot will revert to a line graph where every entry is equally spaced.

Therefore the main thing that needs to be done is getting your X values into numbers.  Be aware that your first few entries are going to be pretty close together.

In order to convert your text to number, you are going to want to convert all your numbers to the same unit.  Alternatively you could change everything to a date.

Doing the date method, I would start with a value of 0 for your first entry and then I would use the following formula and copy down as required to convert your values into dates:

```
=DATE(YEAR($B$2)+IF(RIGHT(A3)="y",LEFT(A3,LEN(A3)-1),0),MONTH($B$2)+IF(RIGHT(A3)="m",LEFT(A3,LEN(A3)-1),0),DAY($B$2))
```

In the example below you will see your original dates in column A,  the converted values using the above formula in column B formatted as dates (YY/MM/DD on my system) and column C is the same value as column B but without a date format applied.  The integers represents the number of days since 1900/01/00.

As an alternate solution, in Column D, I converted everything to the base unit of years.  I entered 0 in D2, and then in D3 I entered the following and copied down:

```
=LEFT(A3,LEN(A3)-1)/IF(RIGHT(A3)="m",12,1)
```

The above formulas were just ways of converting your existing X values from strings/text to numbers.

If your data is actually already numbers then it should just be a matter of selecting scatter plot as your graph option.

[image: POC]

Comment: thanks! Very helpful in solving the timeline issue. I used your column D example. One last question, can I change the x axis labels in the chart? To display 1m, 3m, etc. instead of 10, 20, 30, etc.

Comment: yes and no.  I believe the formatting of the is linked to the formatting of the cells by default.  If not you can format the axis and tell it to link to cell form or if you wish apply the formatting in the axis formatting tab/menu that shows up on the right of the screen.  The issue is you can only apply 1 format as far as I am aware and it will be the format of the first cell.  So you can add "m" to the back of all numbers on the axis, or you can add "y" but not a mix of both.  ALSO note that the ticks on the grid lines may not line up exactly with your data points.

Comment: you could add data labels and format the points with the X coordinate.  In that case if you applied "m" format to the first few points and "y" to the latter points for the cells, the individual units would come through.

Comment: last resort you can manually add the labels with a text box, but you will probably have issues getting correct alignment, and if you graph scale change you will need to manually move the text boxes.

Comment: ok so can I take out the x axis tick marks, then put in text boxes?  i want to line up the ticks but maybe not a good idea.

Comment: you can turn off the axis labelling and add your own label via a superimposed manually drawn textbox if you wish.  I would not go this route though.  Personally I would label you X-axis as years and just show the decimal or fraction instead.  Remember though that only the grid lines get labelled, not the location of your data points.

Comment: thanks, one more question, how come the x axis ends at '70'  there is abit of whitespace till 70.  How can I make it 60 or 60y.

Comment: format the axis.  When you do this a tab/menu will appear on the right hand side.  Normally the upper and lower limits are set to automatic.  They leave you with the option to put in a hard coded value.